# Pycharm puts red lines on valid annotations in python3.7

Tags: python3, pycharm, annotations

When adding type hints to my python3.7 code. I often don't import the actual classes to avoid circular dependencies. Instead I use
`from __future__ import annotations`
to let them be converted to strings during runtime. Despite this being valid code, Pycharm still highlights (red underline) every type hint without an explicit import. Is there:

- A way to turn this off?
- A way to have Pycharm autofill for these hints that aren't imported based off what is found in the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can hover over the the `from __future__ import annotations` until the light glass pop-up then chooses **`Ignore this warning`**.

Or you can check **settings** by (Ctrl + Alt + S) >> `Build, Execution, Deployment`. Then check which error or warning you want to ***Disable/Enable***.

Comment: I can't get a lightbulb to show? just various boxes about the different parts of the statement. I went to Build, execution, deployment and couldn't find any section on warnings/errors? I'm on version 2020.2

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using 2018.3 version  :(

Comment: Ahh what a shame, thanks for the contribution regardless!